# Coldfusion 9.02 ORM mapping for linktable

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have the following tables:
users: userID primaryKey
usersDependencies: userID, dependentUserID

Ex:
users: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
usersDependencies: 
`1, 2`
`1, 3`
`1, 4`
`2, 3`

and the following components:

```
User.cfc

component  persistent="true" output="false" table="users"
{

property name="userID" type="int" unSavedValue="0" fieldtype="id" unique="true" notnull="true" generator="native" default="0" setter="false";

property name="dependencies" fieldtype="many-to-many" cfc="UserDependency" fkColumn="userID" inverseJoinColumn="dependentUserID" 
         singularname="dependency" type="array" cascade="all" linktable="usersDependencies" ;

}

UserDependency.cfc 

component  persistent="true" output="false" table="usersDependencies"
{

property name="userID" fieldtype="id,many-to-one" fkcolumn="userID" cfc="User" insert="false" update="false";


property name="dependentUserID" fieldtype="id,many-to-one" fkcolumn="userID" insert="false" update="false";
```

}

But the above mapping generates the following error:
Repeated column in mapping for entity: UserDependency column: userID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Any idea how to set them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`many-to-many` is usually something one should avoid in ORM.  Try introducing a new entity and restructure the `many-to-many` into 2 `many-to-one` relationships. This generally works better and more flexible to extend later.

Having said that, if `usersDependencies` is just a link table, it should not be an entity.  The `cfc` attribute should set to `User` instead because you want an array of users.  Please follow the cf orm doc closely to make sure you have the concept nailed down.

However, I'm not even sure if ORM would work for this.  I have a feeling `cfdump` may crash even with `TOP 1` since it doesn't play well with lazy loading for your same type referencing many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thank Henry,Yes, all I want is an array of users that depend on the selected user. Then in the UI display that dependents and if it changes then update the dependency in the db

Comment: *"`many-to-many` is usually something one should avoid in ORM"* Is there a reason for that? I've never come across that statement before.  *just curious*

Comment: it's one of those use and you'll know eventually thing.  I've tried using it before but most of the time I'd end up with 2 many-to-one's instead.